# how to compare the current value of a topic with the last one in mqtt using python

Tags: python, mqtt, iot

```
import time

client = mqtt.Client()
client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883)

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Conectando al Servidor - " + str(rc))
    client.subscribe("Valve_OC")
    client.subscribe("Medir")

#def on_message(client, userdata, message):   # The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server
  #  global message_received
   # time.sleep(1)
   # message_received=str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
   # print("received message =", message_received)


def on_message_medir(client, userdata, message):  # The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from topic MEDIR.
    global message_medir
    time.sleep(1)
    message_medir=str(message.payload.decode("utf-8"))
    print("valor medido en arduino =", message_medir)
    valor_mensaje= int(float(message_medir)) #cambiar de string a int el mensaje recibido

    #el potenciometro va de 0 a 1023, simulamos que es el sensor de temperatura
    if (valor_mensaje<=300): #apertura 100%
        print("abrir completamente la valvula")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Abrir,100")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        
        time.sleep(3)

    elif (valor_mensaje>300 and valor_mensaje<=600): #apertura 60%
        print("abrir valvula al 60")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Abrir,60")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
       
   
    elif (valor_mensaje>600 and valor_mensaje<800): #apertura 30%
        print("abrir al 30")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Abrir,30")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
        
  
    elif (valor_mensaje>=800) : #cerrar
        print("cerrar valvula")
        client.publish("Valve_OC", "Cerrar")
        print("valor publicado en topic Valve_OC")
        time.sleep(3)
        

def on_publish(client, obj, mid):
    print("Mensaje: " + str(mid))


def on_subscribe(client, obj, mid, granted_qos):
    print("Subscribed: " + str(mid) + " " + str(granted_qos))


def on_log(client, obj, level, string):
    print(f"Log: {string}")

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_publish = on_publish
client.on_message = on_message
client.message_callback_add("Medir", on_message_medir)
client.on_subscribe = on_subscribe
client.on_log = on_log



client.connect("test.mosquitto.org", 1883)

client.loop_forever()
```

Hello, I'm trying to control a some leds with a potentiometer. When the topic "medir" receive the value of the potentiometer (between 0 and 1024), he compare this information in the phython code (the bucle of Ifs) then the python send to the topic valve_oc the action needed. I'm looking for some way that the message to valve_oc is only sent if the value is different from the last one.

one example: I receive the value of 230, so the mqtt publish in the topic "valve_oc" the string "abrir,100". I want the program to don't send any other value till the value is bigger than 300 so the action will be different.

I've seen in internet that I can use a retained message on mqtt but I don't know how can I do it with my code.

Comment: Retained messages will not help you in this case. Retained messages are more a way for a newly connected client to always get the last value published, not a currently connected client. You should just need another global variable to store that last state in (remember to update it last).

Comment: what do you mean to update it last? the new code?

Comment: You should set the variable holding the last value as the last act of the `on_message` callback

Comment: any idea where can I have more examples about how to use global variable in projects like mine? I have been looking in internet but I don't get any answer

Comment: You already are using global variables e.g. `global message_medir` it should just be a case of storing the value in an equivalent value, then comparing it when a new message comes in.